# Upload analysis results to SonarQube using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner, opencover

I have to Upload analysis results to SonarQube using Jenkins. Please suggest me.

My XML path is - C:\UC\UC_Cart\results.xml. Do I need to download any plugins for the same.
My Issue- How to End Analysis under Sonarqube Scanner for MSBuild.
I mean..Where should I include this section in Jenkins
**End the SonarQube Analysis and upload it to the SonarQube server
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end**

https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772

Followed this URL

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the End Analysis step, which you should find in the list of available build steps. Add it to your job after the build and the analysis report should be sent automatically to the server. There are specifics [in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMSBuild).

Comment: Could you explain me in detail please

Comment: I referred your docs and done the task. But I am unable to Upload XML to Sonar.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include the portion of the job log that is relevant to this.

Comment: Edited the question